# Keycloak delete user give me an 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: wildfly-10, keycloak

I am trying to delete a user from a realm using keycloak admin client api.

I am following an example from here:
https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/43689aefb37540624e35

Here is what my code looks like:

```
Keycloak kc = KeycloakBuilder.builder().serverUrl("https://localhost:8445/auth")
        .realm("sensorcloud-auth").username("admin").password("admin").clientId("admin-cli")
        .clientSecret("b6b4f0ec-9936-46a2-9f40-69c207e2e0f2")
        .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build()).build();
kc.realm("sensorcloud-auth").users().get("a3fdac49-f7eb-4be7-a81f-b48b09a6694c").remove();
```

I can login to keycloak admin console using username admin and password admin, and I am pretty sure there is no typo with other parameters, but every time when I try to delete the user with that userId, I will be given a 401 Unauthorized error. Can someone help me figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which version of keycloak admin client api you are using, with current API there is no remove operation.

It should be `kc.realm(realmName).users().delete(id)` . You can check the [REST API](http://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.2/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource) for Delete User

Comment: Hi, I am user keycloak 3.1. I've tried to use kc.realm(realmName).users().delete(id), but it is still giving me a 401 unauthorized error. My guess is that there are something wrong with the initialization of that kc variable, wildfly doesn't recognize me as an admin user. But I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Have you tried with "master" realm, You can get more information from keycloak server logs

Comment: I didn't try it but I don't think that's the problem. I am not using master realm for my application, I create this sensorcloud-auth realm for my application.

Comment: i believe user is assigned admin role

Comment: Yep, I think so. I can login in to admin console using username admin and password admin, then delete the user manually. But I just cannot do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

We kept getting HTTP 401 status code responses when the hostname stamped on the iss field of the bearer's/user's access token had a different case i.e. lowercase vs. uppercase than the url used to post an HTTP request to keycloak's token endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

While creating Keycloak instance, Realm should be master realm. 
After creating instance with Master Realm, you can delete the user by using your code.